# Rise4Fun.com is down. How else can I get documentation for Z3?

Tags: z3

I have a project that's supposed to be using Z3 but the docs are all on Rise4Fun.com which has been down since Friday. I can't find any information at all about why it is down, if it will be back up, or where other docs might be stored. Does anyone have any information?

Answer (score 2):

Github site has some docs, including the APIs: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki/Documentation

But you're right; without Rise4Fun, the interactive system isn't available anywhere else so far as I know.

Comment: I looked through those yesterday but I just saw docs for different APIs. This might be sufficient but I would ideally be looking for direct Z3 docs. I'm not too worried about the interactive portion of Rise4Fun.